# CamanJS with React

Tags: reactjs, camanjs

I'm trying to use CamanJS with React, I'm installing as a node module with `npm install caman` per the [documentation](http://camanjs.com/) but I am getting an error. I've tried using `require` to bring it in, I've also tried `import`. The package is in my node_modules folder.

Heres the error:

[image]

Console Warning:

[image]

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Please, add the error stack trace as a text, not as an image. Also the console warning

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the issue is that fibers is looking for environment variables, but because you're running it in the browser, it can't find them. npm i -s caman is meant to be used with node. Kinda a bummer.